# Assert command for checking the url in selenium webdriver

Tags: xpath, selenium-webdriver, junit4

As there is no xpath and id for the url on the webpage, how can i check if my actual url is matching with the expected url?

I have provided my code below, but it did not work.

```
String Actualtext = driver.findElement(By.linkText("http://localhost:8080/imdb/homepage")).getText();
Assert.assertEquals(Actualtext, "http://localhost:8080/imdb/homepage" );
System.out.println("URL matching --> Part executed");
```

Answer (score 22, accepted):

You can validate it against the 'current url' as

```
String URL = driver.getCurrentUrl();
Assert.assertEquals(URL, "http://localhost:8080/imdb/homepage" );
```

Comment: Note that in selenium for nodejs, getCurrentUrl returns a promise, not a string (slightly off-topic, but having had this remark here would have saved me quite some time ....)

Answer (score 2):

In Python, it is not `getCurrentUrl`, but

```
driver.current_url
```

Answer (score 1):

`getText()` is used to fetch the visible innertText, You can use the `getAttribute` method to fetch the url (for hyperlink), something like below

```
String Actualtext = driver.findElement("YourElementLocator").getAttribute("href")
Assert.assertEquals(Actualtext, "http://localhost:8080/imdb/homepage" );
System.out.println("URL matching --> Part executed");
```

Comment: But how will you find the element locator? (there is no xpath or id)

Comment: @MinazSayyad, you need a unique identifier xpath, css path, id, class name etc, to locate element. OR you can find all a tags, and check their href attribute one by one.

Answer (score 1):

In selenium webdriver C#

String URL = driver.Url;
Assert.AreEqual(URL, "http://localhost:8080/imdb/homepage");

In Selenium webdriver java

String URL = driver.getCurrentUrl();
Assert.assertEquals(URL, "http://localhost:8080/imdb/homepage" );

Comment: The question concerns JAVA,  your answer is c#,  not sure this is very helpful...